# how to get the name of the category that the user used to add the product to the cart. Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, addtocart, category-products

I need to get at cart what category the product came from. The problem is that the product is added to several different categories, and I need the category in which the user accessed to add the product to the cart. I tried many different things but I couldn't get out of the place. Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 1):

magento does not store product category name where user added it.
You need to do customise it.

For it you need to create custom column in order_item and quote_item  table and with observer (**checkout_cart_product_add_before**) need to save current category name.

Current category

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
$categoryid =$category->getId();
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I need to know which categories the product belongs to, which customer used to add to cart. Example: the product is in "Category A" and "Category B". I need to know in the cart which of the two the user used.

Comment: Are you looking for order item's category name right?

Comment: yes, but getCategoryIds returns all categories that the product belongs to, and the store I'm working with the product is in too many categories. I need the exact category that was used in the purchase.

Comment: as my knowledge, Magento does not save information that user added product from  which categoies pages,
You need to customise it with event.
You pass your category name in before add to cart events and save it on quote and sales order table.

Comment: I need this to use in the "google tag manager" that I was asked and I really don't know how to do it and I couldn't find it anywhere. :/

Comment: Do you know how I would do this with an event?

Comment: Try in your local system.  Add new field in sales_order and quote table.

Comment: create events checkout_cart_product_add_after and save current category page name there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136070/discussion-between-s-p-and-lucas).